# Export / import without using dependency in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on reactJS. I have created two components named App and Layout separately in two two javaScript files. My App should use Layout.

```
//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="react-0.14.7.js"></script>
<script src="react-dom-0.14.7.js"></script>
<script src="browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="/js/components/App/App.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

.

```
//App.js

var Layout = require('/js/components/Layout/Layout.js');    
var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
      return(
          <div>
            <p>hello from App</p>
            <Layout/>
          </div>
      )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

.

```
//Layout.js

Var Layout= React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <p>hi from Layout</p>
            </div>
        ) 
    },

});
//even i tried 'export default Layout'
```

When i used import Layout from ('/js/components/Layout/Layout.js'). It gave an error **unexpected token import**.

With the use of require('/js/components/Layout/Layout.js'). it gave an error **require not defined**.

I tried many ways to get the Layout into App but the only solution i found were to use Browserify, node and npm, webpack...

But i want it to be executed with neither dependency packages nor jars. Is there any way that i can get this done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with a `.` in require `var Layout = require('./js/components/Layout/Layout.js'); `

Comment: `require` is a node.js function. Your browser doesn't have a `require` function.  `import` is a javascript (ES6) statement. I don't think any browser actually support it yet.  You can use a tool like [rollup](https://rollupjs.org) which processes the `import` statements and generates a single file

Comment: @T4rk1n i even tried that! but no result.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock yes i am aware of that. But my only intent is not to use any external sources. But thanks for **rollup**. I never knew this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. Both Browserify and Webpack are module bundlers and will do file bundling for you. I'd recommend you to understand first the purpose of both tools.

The first thing Browserify website tells you is its sole purpose:

> Browserify lets you require('modules') in the browser by bundling up all of your dependencies.

And same story for Webpack:

> Webpack is a module bundler for modern JavaScript applications. When webpack processes your application, it recursively builds a dependency graph that includes every module your application needs, then packages all of those modules into a small number of bundles - often only one - to be loaded by the browser.

Those are just very short descriptions of both of them.

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoBenitez for the update. I totally understood the concept. but i am just trying to make it work with out external source. So, i am just trying for alternatives!

Comment: in that case what you'll need to do is a full namespace by yourself using IIFE expressions and then forcing the order of execution of the files so they are available when you need them (i.e. Layout.js should be referenced before App.js). Does it make sense?

Comment: Do browserify requires additionaly grunt/gulp?

Comment: yes because you need to run the task to create the bundles in the right order. Always what matters is the output file which is what your server will return, there the files have to be in the right position

Comment: Yes, now its clear to me as grunt and gulp are Task runners. So instead of all these, can i just use NodeJS and React?

Comment: but again don't confuse the browser with the backend, the right answer is that you can use NPM, Webpack and React. You need a module bundler for managing your dependencies. Alternatively you can use Gulp Browserify and React